# How to create an element auto-instantiated array such as the int arrays of an user-defined type?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Upon declaring an int array such as:

```
int[] test = new int[5];
```

All of the elements of the array are automatically initialized to `0`. Is there anyway I can create a class that will auto-initialized when an array is created such as the int arrays?

For example:

```
MyClass[] test2 = new MyClass[5];
```

Will still require me to call the constructor; but with `int` the constructor is magically called.

What code/operators of the `int` class that allows this behavior?

Comment: Make `MyClass` a struct :-)

Comment: @Jordão how come when a regular int is declared you have to call the default constructor but when an array int is declared you do not need to call the default constructor?

Comment: The default constructor is called automatically for value types in that case.

Comment: Jordão is correct. A struct always have a default constructor where as a class is not bound by this restriction.

Comment: @SimonBelanger but why does the default constructor not magically call when you just to `int x;` why does it magically call the default constructor when you create space for an array. Surely there must be some additional code hidden in the struct that could be applied to a class?

Comment: Ask one or at least in the same sense of question per post is just fine. If you are going to ask a different question, it would be better to *ask a new question*.

Comment: @KenKin my original question is how to make a class initialize exactly like an int. I haven't quite got that answer but rather got work arounds. However some of them are really cool and definitely am considering them it still seems the answer I am getting to my question is a simple no. Meaning how does the struct name followed by [] call the default constructor. Okay fine I will ask a different question about it.

Comment: If you have the presumption of **there must be an operator plays this trick**, then the question turns **unanswerable** if there's not.

Comment: @KenKin I'm sort of confused now and think my real question has to do with default initialization values and how to change them or create a new primitive value type with a unique default value. Actually my question is perhaps begging what code is going on inside those index operators that make them different. The answer seems to be a simple the compiler does it and you can't access it because it is the base structure of the language sort of thing.

Comment: Take a look at [Overloadable Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8edha89s.aspx). Note that, *square brackets* is **not** overloadable, and **indexers** is **not** for instantiation.

Comment: @KenKin I understand that indexers are not for instantiation in the case of classes but in the case of structs they are being instantiated by the index...

Comment: **Titanic** may mean a ship, or a movie about that ship, then we say the name Titanic, what it is? It's according the context. Similarly, `[]` involves when we create an array, or when we access an element of the array, the same symbol but the different meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

I removed the constraint of `new()` to accept a class without **parameterless constructor**. However, this would also accept an abstract class or an interface be used as the type parameter, and it will throw the exception at runtime if the type cannot be instantiated.

One thing further to mention is, the `CreateArray<T>` method would **also deal with value types**; that is, except pointer types and the types which have `TypeAttributes.Abstract`<sup>1</sup> attribute, you can create any type of array with it.

<sup>1</sup>: Interfaces are also abstract. Static classes are abstract & sealed.

---

The difference is that `int` is a value type, but your `class` might not be.

Declare `MyClass` as `struct MyClass{ }`, then it would behaves as same as you create an `int` array.

If you do want to create an array of reference types, then the following code just do that:

```
public static class TestClass {
    public static T[] CreateArray<T>(int length, params object[] args) {
        var elementType=typeof(T);
        var array=(T[])Array.CreateInstance(elementType, length);

        for(; length-->0;
            array[length]=(T)Activator.CreateInstance(elementType, args))
            ;

        return array;
    }

    public static void TestMethod() {
        var array=CreateArray<MyClass>(5, /* default arguments */ );
    }
}
```

The default argument are the arguments that you are passing to the constructor. The code creates an array, then create instances of the type with the given arguments and initialize the array with the instances.

Note that `length` are passed as the array size, and then used as index in the for-loop.

The documentation:

- [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx)
- [Array.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that MyClass is a reference type so the default value is null. Because you don't initialize the objects in the array, they are null. You could write a helper like:

```
T[] InitializeArray<T>(int length) where T : new()
{
    T[] array = new T[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = new T();
    }

    return array;
}
```

and then initialize your array:

```
MyClass[] something = InitializeArray<MyClass>(5);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `int` array isn't magically set to 0. `Int` is a value type with a default value of 0 where as `MyClass` is a reference type with a default value of `null`.

If you want to create an array with everything initialize, you can use a fluent extension method:

```
public static T[] InitializeAll<T>(this T[] source) where T : new()
{
    if(source != null)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
        {
            source[i] = new T();
        }
    }

    return source;
}

var test2 = new MyClass[5].InitializeAll();
```

Or mandaleeka solution, using a loop.

Edit: I'm reinstating my original solution as Guffa's comment need it for context

```
public static T[] CreateArray<T>(int size) where T : new()
{
     return Enumerable.Repeat(new T(), size).ToArray();      
}
```

Comment: That will create an array full of references to a single instance, not a new instance for each item in the array.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Gross oversight on my part. I've edited my solution to keep the spirit of using Linq, but at this point, mandaleeka solution is the most effective.

Comment: Hmm it appears my mistake is not realizing int is a `struct` and not a `class`, structs automatically default to 0 no matter what and there is no way to override this type of behavior I guess?

Comment: There isn't a way, unfortunately. Just to correct you one more time, a struct isn't necessarily defaulting to 0. If you create a custom struct with one `int` property and implement a default constructor that set the value of that property to 1, then your struct with "default" to that property being 1 at initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Change MyClass to be struct datatype, i.e.: `public struct MyClass`.

Comment: I guess this does answer my question as how to make it exactly like int. My mistake is thinking int is a class. So there is no way to override or custom set a default value type?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the difference between [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

"A data type is a value type if it holds the data within its own memory allocation." whereas, "A reference type contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the data."

Common examples of value types:

- All numeric data types
- Boolean, Char, and Date
- All structures, even if their members are reference types
- Enumerations, since their underlying type is always SByte, Short, Integer, Long, Byte, Short, UInteger, or ULong

Common examples of reference types:

- String
- All arrays, even if their elements are value types
- Class types, such as [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- Delegates

All value types are initialized to a default value(zero for numeric types), and reference types point to `null`.

A declaration of:

```
int num;
```

Does not initialize the variable `num`. Therefore `num` cannot be used. C# requires that each variable is set to some value(whether `null` or a number) before it is used.

The same goes for reference types:

```
//un-initialized, therefore cannot be used until a value is given(A compiler error will occur)
string str;
```

However, a declaration of:

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
```

Causes the array to be initialized(therefore calling the array's constructor) which then causes each of the elements to be initialized to the default value of int(i.e. zero).

Using the same method on a reference type yields the same result:

```
string[] strings = new string[5];
```

Causes the array to be initialized and therefore creating an array of `null` strings(which is the default value of all reference types).

[Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ah19swz4.aspx) are the data type that you are looking for.  Structures are value types and therefore cannot be set to `null`. Since they cannot be set to `null`, they must have some default value. The default value is determined by a [default constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor).

A structure can be defined like this:

```
struct MyStructName
{
    //Members of the struct, like a class, default value is 0.
    int myNumber;

    //Structs can have members whose data type is a reference type
    //Default value is null.
    string myString;

    //Every struct has a default constructor, though you cannot define one.
    //The compiler generates one for you that initializes every member to it's
    //default value.

}
```

This will define a data type that contains the members, myNumber and myString, that cannot be set to `null`.

```
//Array of MyStructName, the default constructor is called and each value is initialized
MyStructName[] data = new MyStructName[5];

//Loop and print results
for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    //Prints the index, number and the string or "null"
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: myNumber: {1}, myString: \"{2}\"", i, data[i].myNumber, data[i].myString != null ? data[i].myString : "null"); 
}
```

Comment: In a `struct` I cannot create a parameterless constructor. What is the code inside of int that tells it to go to 0 as default. How about 1 or 2 instead? I want to know specifically what code is causing it to initialize when the array is placed. Why does making an array declare the constructor vs just declaring it by itself. Ordinarily an array does not call the default constructor there must be some additional code.

Comment: Why does a struct initialize when an array is declared but not when the struct itself is declared?

Comment: `Since they cannot be set to null, they must have some default value.` So a non-nullable class can be set to null? Or are all classes nullable?

Comment: All **classes** can be set to null. A struct **cannot** be set to null. You are not just **defining** an array. The `new` keyword causes a new array to be initialized, therefore causing each element to be initialized.  There is no specific code in C# that causes a constructor to be called for intergers, the code for Int32 has an internal member whose type is `int`. Sorry about the default(parameter less) constructor (C# does not let you define one), I will remove it.

Comment: Out of curiosity since you mentioned C# does not, do you know any common languages maybe such as Java that support this functionality?

Comment: Sorry, but not really. Java does not support what you want because you cannot define a value type(structs), only reference types(classes). The best that I can think of for default initialization is to write an extension method like this `public T[] Initialize<T>(this T[] array) where T : new()` and then inside the method loop through the elements of the array and call the default constructor. That will work for classes with a default constructor. You would then call it like any extension method. `myArray.Initialize()`